# How to avoid type checker warnings due to default values set in __init__?

Tags: python-3.x, pyright

In my app there are many cases of classes that essentially behave like this:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.subject = None

    def set_subject(self, subject: SpecificClass) -> None:
        self.subject = subject

    def do_something_with_subject(self) -> None:
        self.subject.do_stuff()
```

It's an invariant of the program that `do_something_with_subject()` is always called after `set_subject()`, but I must create class `A` before I know what to set the subject to, so right now I'm setting default values in `__init__()`. In the case of `subject`, the only logical default value is `None`.

Now for the problem: my static type checker (pyright) complains about `self.subject.do_stuff()`. Since it sees in `__init__()` that `subject` can be `None`, it tells me that `do_stuff()` is not a member of `None`. All very reasonable, except that this is not a warning I wish to see, given how my program operates. I also:

- Like the idea of declaring all instance variables in `__init__()`. It gives you an overview of the class contents, and I also hear that some IDEs look into `__init__()` for autocompletion information.
- Don't want to use type-checker-specific directives in the code to silence this warning, because I want other developers to be free to use their own preferred type checker.
- Don't want to annotate `subject` with something like `Any` that excludes it from the type checking.

Is there some way I can have my cake and eat it too in this case? Keep `subject` under type checking scrutiny, keep it somehow declared in `__init__()`, and not have the type checker think it can be `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `cast`.
`self.subject = cast(SpecificClass, None)` will return the value (`None`) unchanged, but will signal to the type checker that it has a specific type (`SpecificClass`).

Answer (score 0):

A painless way to appease the type checker is to make this the first line of `do_something_with_subject`.

```
assert self.subject is not None
```

This certainly appeases `mypy`, which pieces everything together from this line.